# full screen header section

Tags: css, html

Im trying to make a full screen header section at the top of my page, but I cant get it working for all devices / monitor. What is the industry standard for doing this, javascript, css? is there a set height I should just use? Right now my way works on everything but mobile devices it keeps repeating down the page again and again.

```
<body>
    <header>
         <h1>Logo</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="page">
         <p>content</p>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    header {
          hieght:100vh;
          width:100%;
          background-image:url('image.png');
          background-size:cover;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: hieght should be height.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what 100% means, right now it's saying the width of header is 100% of nothing. Add

```
body{
  width: 100%;
}
```

You've also spelled height wrong.

Here's how I would do it.

```
<body>
    <header>
         <h1>Logo</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="page">
         <p>content</p>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    header {
          height:100%;
          width:100%;
          background: green;
          background-size:cover;
    }
</style>
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J98df6LxrrcqUJ9HpC5k?p=preview). Switched BG to green to visualize it.