# Almost full screen header problems

Tags: html, css

I've recently tried out to make a website with a bar on top and with an image that cover the rest of the screen, much like this [X-theme demo](http://theme.co/x/demo/integrity/7/). I've managed to get it right in proportion (with a lot of help from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640103/full-screen-header-section)).

```
<body>
<div id="block">
      <p>logo</p>
</div>
<header>
     <h1>jumbotron</h1>
</header>
<div id="page">
     <p>content</p>
</div>
```

```
*{
margin: 0;
}

#block {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  background-size:cover;
  }

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
      height:90vh;
      width:100%;
      background: green;
      background-size:cover;
}
```

This solution is however not so practical. When you shrink down your browser window, the bar on top (naturally) shrinks as well. Adding a logo would then be impossible, so I wonder if there is any way to make the bars size constant, while the header still takes up the rest of the screen?

I would really appreciate some help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Because `vh` and `px` are two different units, it is not possible to do some math with them like `100vh - 30px`, but it's possible using some jQuery/JavaScript.</strike> I'll give you an example using jQuery *(Be sure to add a fixed height to the header)*.

*On the end of this answer there is a CSS-only solution for this problem. Found out about it later.*

**This is the html code:**

```
<header class="header">YOUR LOGO HERE</header>
<section class="jumbotron">CONTENT HERE</section>
<section class="content">SOME OTHER CONTENT HERE</section>
```

**And this should be the javascript one:**

```
var resizePage = function() {
  var headerHeight = $('.header').outerHeight() // Getting the height of the header
    , pageHeight = $(window).height();          // Getting the height of the window

  $('.jumbotron').css('height', (pageHeight-headerHeight));
}

$(window).on('resize', resizePage());   // Fire every time the page resizes
resizePage();                           // Fire once the site is running
```

Here is a JSFiddle working with the snippets I told you: [CLICK ME](http://jsfiddle.net/ekrff9t2/)

**UPDATE:** Just found out that CSS is providing a `calc()` method. Here is another JSfiddle with this method: [CLICK ME, TOO](http://jsfiddle.net/d44jcdk2/). So it is possible using pure CSS, but be aware of the [browser support for this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```
.jumbotron {
   /* Viewport height 100 minus 50px calculated using pure css */
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```